# use different data types in xaml properties

Tags: xaml, types, data-binding, maui

```xml
<Picker
            Title="Select a Profile"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ProfileManager.Profiles}" 
            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProfile, Mode=TwoWay}"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            SelectedIndex="1"
            HeightRequest="200"
            WidthRequest="325"
            Margin="10"
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Secondary}">
        </Picker>
```

the `itemSource` property have `x:DataType="ViewModels:ParametersViewModel"` datatype but the `ItemDisplayBinding` have `x:DataType="Models:Profile"` datatype.

How can I define these datatypes seperatly?

Comment: you shouldn't need to.  `DataType` is purely a XAML helper to provide Intellisense, you don't have to use it.

Comment: NOTE: If this won't run due to datatype errors, try removing ALL `x:DataType` properties throughout this xaml file. Once Xamarin sees one x:DataType, it has to be told correct ones after that. If you DO use `x:DataType`, the types of the two properties in the `Picker` element are NOT what you should enter. Rather, you need to enter the DataType **of the class that CONTAINS THOSE TWO PROPERTIES**. Add to question the declaration of the class that is the BindingContext of the page or container Picker is within. Include the two properties `ProfileManager` and `SelectedProfile`...

Comment: ... If `ProfileManager` and `SelectedProfile` are NOT PROPERTIES of your current `BindingContext`, then go read more about Binding in Maui (or in Xamarin Forms; works the same). Binding is ALWAYS to properties of  some BindingContext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure If this answer works for you but you can define different data types inside same XAML file by clarifying `Ancestor Type`.

```
<ContentPage 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:Models="clr-namespace:Models"
    xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:ViewModels" 
    x:DataType="viewmodel:ParametersViewModel">

    <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding ProfileManager.Profiles}" 
            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Models:Profile}}, Path=Name}"/>
</ContentPage>
```

Once you set a DataType in the root (in this case ContentPage), all the bindings of its children will go to that datatype by default.

Comment: thanks! this solved my issue but why intellisence autocompletion won't works on the `Path` property?

Comment: unfortunately, when you access properties/methods over AncestorType, intellisense won't work afaik. It is not maui related. Same thing happens with Xamarin and WPF also.

Answer (score 0):

From document [Populate a Picker with data using data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/picker?view=net-maui-7.0#populate-a-picker-with-data-using-data-binding), we could find that

> A Picker can be also populated with data by using data binding to bind
> its ItemsSource property to an IList collection.

```
<Picker Title="Select a monkey"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" />
```

> When binding to a list of objects, the Picker must be told which
> property to display from each object. This is achieved by setting the
> `ItemDisplayBinding` property to the required property from each object.
> In the code examples above, the Picker is set to display each
> `Monkey.Name` property value.

So, the `ItemDisplayBinding` property(`Name`) in your code above should be the required property from each object(`Profile`) in your `ItemsSource`(`ProfileManager.Profiles`).

In fact, we don't have to or need to specify what you call `x:DataType` for the Picker.

**Note:**

You can find the official sample here [MonkeyAppPicker](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/UserInterface/MonkeyAppPicker),though it is coded in xamarin , but the implementation on MAUI is almost the same.